# How can I replace a string containing character ` in bash?

Tags: perl, replace

I have a string like this

```
export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA`
```

and I would like to replace with this one

```
export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
```

I'm trying to use perl like this, bu it doesn't work

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's#\`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA\`"#export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf#g' fileDirectory
```

Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did it work? If not - what's the output are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s#\`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf $EASY_RSA\`"#...#g
    ^                         ^          ^
    |                         |          |
    +------------+------------+       Not in 
                 |                    input
            Not escaped.              string
     Perl interpolates $EASY_RSA
```

Fix:

```
sudo perl -i -pe's#`\$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf \$EASY_RSA`#export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf#g' file
```